# Passing dot operator to java from ajax call

Tags: java, ajax

I am passing a string with "dot" (.) operator, when it is passing to java, string which i am passing with dot is not properly passing.

Example :

I am passing

http://localhost:8080/Project/some/test/value1/value2/value3/192.168.200.136

But while doing this the data which i am getting in my java class (@pathvaribale) as 192.168.200

How to pass this value properly

Ajax call look like

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : urlpath,
            success : function(data) {
//do something
}
});
```

Comment: First of all, I would suggest using `@RequestParam` to pass your values to the controller, which makes your request look like `http://localhost:8080/Project/some/test?value1=value&value2=value&value3=value&value4=192.168.200.136`
In this case, the order of the passed values does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a regex mapping `{q:.+}` in `@RequestMapping` like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{q:.+}")
```